# how to write a csv file using a constant value in the file using R

Tags: r, csv, file

I have a data frame , use this dummy data frame as example

```
name = rep("ID1",3))
city = c("London", "Paris", "Tokio")
df = data.frame(name = name, city =  city)
```

I would like to export the data frame in a csv format (`write_csv`) but I would like to name it using the value in col name (ID1) as name ('automatically'):

```
write_csv(df, 'valueofthecolname_df.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the name you want by pasting pieces of text together:

```
write_csv(df, paste0(df$name[1], '_df.csv'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think you wanted unique IDs, so I changed the `name` dataset.

Using `purrr` package, you can iterate over the entire list and create a CSV file for each ID.

```r
name <- paste0("ID", 1:3) # Changed this to have unique IDs
city <- c("London", "Paris", "Tokio")

my_df <- data.frame(name = name, city = city)

my_df %>%
  split(name) %>%
  purrr::iwalk(~ readr::write_csv(.x, paste0("~/Desktop/", .y, ".csv")))
```